# asp.net keystore for password storage?

Tags: asp.net, security, keystore

I know that encrypted passwords can be stored in the web.config or hashed and salted passwords can be stored in a database, but is it possible to store passwords in something like a keystore?

Would a keystore even be a good idea to store 'service account' passwords that are needed by an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest analogue to a Java keystore in .NET/Windows world is DPAPI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API). It stores encrypted values in the Windows registry, with the encryption key derived from system or user account level secrets.

It is in fairly wide use, though a paper was released at the 2010 Black Hat DC Conference detailing a crack against it ([Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B9MkvtnWPqvEMmI2NWU1YTUtZDIyMC00Mjk3LWEyZGUtOGM2YzA3NzUzMTk2&hl=fr&pli=1)).

Prior to that paper (and if MS fixes it at some point) I would highly recommend DPAPI for exactly what you are describing.

At this point, using DPAPI is probably (and unfortunately) the best option. A mitigating factor is that the crack is highly technical, difficult to execute, and requires quite a bit of OS access to pull off. A breach of a DPAPI key is most likely to be pulled off by a trusted insider with access to the system, as opposed to an external attacker.