# Key Store Equivalence to C#?

Tags: c#, java, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net keystore for password storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767018/asp-net-keystore-for-password-storage)

What is the equivalent of keystore in C#?

Basically I have an encryption key which needs to be stored safely.

Comment: @hcb what is the advantage of using a keystore to encrypt a key ? I am currently using a CONSTANT FINAL key.. so its not accessable by the user..